# Should 'solar-power' be renamed 'photo-voltaic cell'?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

The tag 'Solar Power' is used as a synonym for 'photo-voltaic' cell/array at present. This term used is not unacceptable. It may be misleading to a nouveau who comes to SEx.SE, perhaps, to seek a reference... or the vice-versa.

- Should a tag 'photo-voltaic cell' be created?
- Should such created tag coexist as a synonym for 'solar-power'?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why this term is unacceptable?  I'm aware that there exist other forms of solar power, but it's not incorrect, or is it?

Comment: @gerrit: It's not at all incorrect; merely that 'PV' is ... more focused

Comment: There at least [one solar power question not about PV](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/110/33).  And my wife has a t-shirt reading *What if we could harness the solar wind for energy?* ;-)

Answer (score 3):

To me [solar-power](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-power) and the proposed tag [photovoltaic-cell](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photovoltaic-cell) serve different purposes. [solar-power](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-power) is about energy source design, specifically designs made to draw power from the sun. [photovoltaic-cell](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photovoltaic-cell) is about the use of a specific technology, regardless of the context of its use. I think [solar-power](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-power) should remain and not be made a synonym of anything. Likewise, [photovoltaic-cell](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photovoltaic-cell) should not be made a synonym of [solar-power](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-power). However, I see no reason to go out of our way to create a tag for that technology, when no one has seen a need to categorize questions that way.